# Node Red multiple values to influxDB

Tags: javascript, influxdb, node-red

i try with Node Red to build an query to send multiple values to an influxDB from a loop with this code:

```html
var inputArray = msg.payload;
var lenInputArray =inputArray.length;
var modbusStartRegister = 14000;

var sendString = "";

var msg93 ={};


for (i = 0; i < lenInputArray; i++) {
    var actRegister = modbusStartRegister +i;
    var actValue = inputArray[i];
    if ( i >=1){
        sendString =  sendString + " ,"
    }
    sendString = sendString +"{register: " + actRegister +"," +"value: " + actValue +"}";
    if ( i ==(lenInputArray-1)){
        sendString =  sendString + "]"
    }
}

msg93.payload = sendString;

    
return msg93
```

But the insert in the influxDB is one line it looks at them interpreted as an complete string. How can I build or convert the string that the DB accept them as individual entry? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are building a string, node an object.

You can build the array object on the fly like this:

```
var inputArray = msg.payload;
var lenInputArray =inputArray.length;
var modbusStartRegister = 14000;

var payload = [];

var msg93 ={};


for (i = 0; i < lenInputArray; i++) {
    var temp = {};
    temp.register = modbusStartRegister +i;
    temp.value = inputArray[i];
    payload.push(temp);

}

msg93.payload = payload;


return msg93
```